# NetBeans Take long time to install Cordova apk in Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans

I'm New in CORDOVA, i have install NetBeans IDE For Develop Cordova app,but When I run app in emulator its take to much time to install apk.

Comment: try changing your editor, if possible switch to Visual Studio Code, its light weight and compatibility is good

Comment: is Visual Studio fast for build apk?

Comment: its fast for ios too...if building apk is taking time, it can have many other reasons as well, like your system ram, howmuch ram have you allocated in gradle.properties. but yes visual studio is fast and lightweight

Comment: ok, i will try it